# Graph API - BadRequest on sending channel messages with @mention

Tags: asp.net-web-api, graph, send, channel, mention

We had some code that has been working for the past 10 months (since it was developed) and just stopped working this afternoon. It's a WebAPI code to send a channel message mentioning the bot and a user, which now is returning "Bad Request. Invalid request body was sent."

If the "Mentions" property is not provided, the call works, and the message is sent without the @mentions. So, I wonder if there was a breaking change in this API that's now expecting a different format for the "Mentions" property.

It's quite simple to reproduce by following the example code found in [the Microsoft Graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2--a-user-in-a-channel-message).

I'm posting here in the hope some fellow dev spots something obvious or is aware of an alternative way of using the API that it might stop complaining, as Microsoft takes forever to reply.

Here's the code we have that can lead me to discover the issue:

```
private async Task SendMentionToTheBotAsync(GraphServiceClient onBehalfOfClient, string userName, string teamId, string channelId)
{
        var supportAgentUser = await onBehalfOfClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

        var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
        {
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = $"<at id=\"0\">{Configuration["BotName"]}</at>: This is the start of the conversation between {userName} and <at id=\"1\">{supportAgentUser.DisplayName}</at>."
            },
            Mentions = new List<ChatMessageMention>
              {
                new ChatMessageMention
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    MentionText = Configuration["BotName"],
                    Mentioned = new IdentitySet
                    {
                        Application = new Identity
                        {
                            DisplayName = Configuration["BotName"],
                            Id = Configuration["BotAppId"],
                            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string,object>
                            {
                                {
                                    "applicationIdentityType", "bot"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ChatMessageMention
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    MentionText = supportAgentUser.DisplayName,
                    Mentioned = new IdentitySet
                    {
                        User = new Identity
                        {
                            DisplayName = supportAgentUser.DisplayName,
                            Id = supportAgentUser.Id,
                            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string,object>
                            {
                                {
                                    "userIdentityType", "aadUser"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        await onBehalfOfClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Messages
                              .Request()
                              .AddAsync(chatMessage);
    }
```

Comment: If you want someone expert in webapi to look at this, you should take more care with your tags.  Add the relevant webapi tag and remove the graph tag.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Support responded with :

"Thank you for contacting Microsoft Support.

I understand the issue is related to the post messages to Teams. Based on the screenshot, it seems you are using mention to a channel. It's possible that you are using key "conversationIdentityType@odata.type" in your request.

Could you please try to remove "conversationIdentityType@odata.type" key from the request body and try again. It should work. It is because deployment is on the way in the Asia region. Once it's 100% rolled out, this key WILL NOT be entertained in the request."

Removed the key and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it here Michael. I'm having trouble manipulating the request since I'm using Graph SDK. The code I posted assembles the ChatMessage object, and then I use the code below to send it. Any ideas on how to remove the key from the request? I already tried specifying the oData property in the Chat Message to a string. Empty, but it complained about an invalid oData informed.

 await onBehalfOfClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Messages
                                  .Request()
                                  .AddAsync(chatMessage);

Comment: paulo, responded with a screenshot, but my answer was hidden. My problem was in a Power Automate Flow using an authenticated Graph query posting to Teams. 

After removing the key above my json is : 

{
  "body": {
    "content": "Power Automate Flow <at id=\"0\">Channel1</at>",
    "contentType": "html"
  },
  "mentions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "mentionText": "Channel1",
      "mentioned": {
        "conversation": {
          "id": "19:1234@thread.tacv2",
          "displayName": "Channel1",
          "conversationIdentityType": "channel"
        }
     }
  }
 ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Paulo,

Unfortunately i am not a programmer. I am using Graph calls in a Microsoft 365 Power Automate workflow. I have an app that i use to get the Authorisation Bearer token and then post to Teams messages using a graph HTTP action.

Here is the syntax of the HTTP ( purple items are variables if u r not familiar with Flow )

[click to view image of Power Automate workflow HTTP action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HyNC.png)